# How to take Screenshot of entire Webview in Android programatically?

Tags: android, android-webview, webpage-screenshot

I am able to take the screenshot of the content that is visible on the webpage, but how I do take the entire webpage screenshot?

This is what I am currently doing

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
view.draw(canvas);

fos = new FileOutputStream(path);
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, fos);
fos.flush();
fos.close()
```

Comment: The solution you mentioned uses capturePicture(), which is deprecated now

Comment: Can you please try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/51983524/10711216

Comment: @Mohan Didn't help

Comment: May be this may help you : - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745988/how-can-i-programmatically-take-a-screenshot-of-a-webview-capturing-the-full-pa
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35933030/how-to-get-webview-screenshot